# How to display multiple Post meta_key/meta_values by SQL query

Tags: php, custom-field, post-meta, sql

I haven't found a solution to displaying multiple postmeta meta_key/meta_values by SQL query of a post. I am using the Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) plugin on another website and trying to pull the contents of the posts on a secondary website. Everything displays well except it is not able to display more meta_values.

Here is my code:

```
$mydb = new wpdb('database_name','database_user','database_pw','database_host');
    $rows = $mydb->get_results("
        SELECT P.ID, P.post_title, P.post_content, P.post_author, meta_value
        FROM wp_posts AS P
        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS PM on PM.post_id = P.ID 
        WHERE P.post_type = 'post' and P.post_status = 'publish'

        and meta_key = 'job_title'
        and meta_key = 'company_email' //2nd meta_key I need to work

        ORDER BY P.post_date DESC
        ");

foreach ($rows as $row) :
    echo $row->meta_value;
endforeach;
```

As you can see, I am able to retrieve just one meta_key/meta_value but have multiple fields to display.

Comment: Have you considered using a REST API endpoint instead so that you can do it on the other site using APIs instead of a raw SQL query? This query is going to be very *expensive*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change where clause with `or`

```
SELECT P.ID, P.post_title, P.post_content, P.post_author, meta_value
FROM wp_posts AS P
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS PM on PM.post_id = P.ID
WHERE P.post_type = 'post' and P.post_status = 'publish' and ( meta_key = 'job_title' or meta_key = 'company_email' )
ORDER BY P.post_date DESC
```

but this sql will return the same post in 2 row for your meta key and value;
and you will get something like

```
+-----+------------+--------------+-------------+----------+------------+
| ID  | post_title | post_content | post_author | meta_key | meta_value |
+-----+------------+--------------+-------------+----------+------------+
| 10  | Post Title | Post Content |           1 |   key1   |   value1   |
+-----+------------+--------------+-------------+----------+------------+
| 10  | Post Title | Post Content |           1 |   key2   |   value2   |
+-----+------------+--------------+-------------+----------+------------+
```

and if you need to get the meta key as column and meta value as value of the correspondence column you need to pivot the row to column

```
SELECT P.ID, P.post_title, P.post_content, P.post_author,
    MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'job_title', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS job_title,
    MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'company_email', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS company_email
FROM wp_posts AS P
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS PM on PM.post_id = P.ID
WHERE P.post_type = 'post' and P.post_status = 'publish'
ORDER BY P.post_date DESC
```

this will return the result as a single row like this

```
+-----+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+---------------+
| ID  | post_title | post_content | post_author | job_title | company_email |
+-----+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+---------------+
| 10  | Post Title | Post Content |           1 | job title | company@email |
+-----+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+---------------+
```

Comment: Thank you, your second method works well but it returns only a single row as mentioned. Is there a way to show all posts in P.post_type = 'post'?

Comment: if you have more then 1 post in your db (check your `where` clause) this will return the rows even if those post doesn't have job_title or company_email meta.