# Trying to retrieve meta values from three different meta keys and display in rows

Tags: php, custom-field

I have the same problem is outlined here: [How to display multiple Post meta_key/meta_values by SQL query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/251944/how-to-display-multiple-post-meta-key-meta-values-by-sql-query?newreg=688118e1cf81422780a8af09aa6b604c)

The final comment does provide the correct result, but only ever displays one row because it is using MAX. I definitely have more than 1 post. Does anyone have any advice as to how to return the rows requested from all posts?

Comment: And why do you want to do it with SQL query and not with WP functions?

Comment: What I am actually trying to do is use wptables and I need to build the query. Otherwise I also need to figure out how to have the columns sortable, searchable, editable, etc. I thought I was keeping it simple